# How is GoogleAPI + Python supposed to work in 2020? Conflicting information

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-api

Tools: Django 2.0, Python 3.7. Google API creds are created.
Using this flow: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_4

Everything I can find on getting me through this is from 2011-2014 and appears to be deprecated or on its way out so I'm not sure which API I'm supposed to use. I've reviewed every topic on SO I can find but each one looks different and uses different APIs.

The **actual problem** with this code is that I receive a **null** value back from the GoogleAPI and I can't figure out how to get the actual data from the authorized user. I'm not sure if this is because I'm using the wrong flow or there is a mistake in the code.

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from users.models import CustomUser, OAuthCredentials
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from urllib.request import urlopen


JSON_PATH = 'users/client_secret.json'
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000/users/oauth/google/callback/'
API_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'openid',
]


def oauth_google(request):

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        JSON_PATH,
        scopes= API_SCOPE,
    )

    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI

    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline',
        include_granted_scopes='true')

    return redirect(authorization_url)

def oauth_google_callback(request):

    state = request.GET.get('state',None)
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        JSON_PATH,
        scopes = API_SCOPE,
        state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI


    authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()

    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

    credentials = flow.credentials

    response = request.GET.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + credentials.token)

    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

Any help is appreciated in getting the actual appropriate response back. I am trying to get email and profile information.

p.s. I know there are Django libraries I can use. I will use them if I have to but there are other APIs I would like to use in the future and I will need to know how to do this anyways. I also prefer to have more control over my code whenever possible.

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you calling a google API? I see you authenticating but not actually any calls to APIs.  You do appear to be hard coding a call to the userinfo endpoint.  WIth the full token credential object instead of just the access token.

Comment: `response = request.GET.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + credentials.token)` This is what is used to actually return the user information according to other SO answers. So after authenticating, isn't that the call?

Comment: credentials.token is the access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found these two lines of code buried in some random sample code online. Hope it helps others. Is there a doc source for these types of calls in the future?

```
service = build('oauth2', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
data = service.userinfo().get().execute()
```